# Compiler Optimisation in the context of copy elision

Tags: c++11, copy-elision

My reference is to the code segment presented as part of the follow-up discussion on the below write-up:

[Lambdas vs. Closures](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/lambdas-vs.-closures-scott-meyers)

The pertinent code segment is

```
struct PrintD
{
~PrintD()
{
cout << "dtor" << endl;
}
};

int main()
{
PrintD d;
auto f = [d](){
d;
};

cout << "--" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

When the above code is compiled using GCC without the `-fno-elide-constructors` option, the following output is generated:

```
--
dtor
dtor
```

When recompiled using the `-fno-elide-constructors` option, the following output is generated:

```
dtor
--
dtor
dtor
```

Is the understanding correct that in the latter case, the additional `dtor` print out corresponds to the temporary being destroyed, which is created during the capture of `d` by copy inside `f`?

Answer (score 0):

The "extra" copy comes from the copy-initialization of `f` from the lambda (the lambda is a prvalue).

Since C++17's change to prvalue materialization, there is never any extra copy here. You should find that if compiling with `-std=c++17` you never get the extra copy, even passing the elision flag.

A simpler code demonstrating the same issue would be `auto f = PrintD();`.

---

In C++14 you could mandate avoiding the copy by:

```
auto&& f = [d] () {d;};
```

although personally I'd trust the compiler to do it and assume we'll be moving onto C++17 soon enough.